# WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.warnings.FindBugs': unstableTotalAll

Tags: jenkins, console, spotbugs

I'm seeing the following log line on a Jenkins job (using Pipeline syntax)

> WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.warnings.FindBugs': unstableTotalAll

after which there's a notable delay of usually 3-4 minutes in the Jenkins console. e.g.

```
17:07:27  WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.warnings.FindBugs': unstableTotalAll
17:10:47  [FindBugs] Searching for all files in 'directory path' that match the pattern '**/spotbugsXml.xml'
```

Google is not showing an exact match for this issue. Any ideas on what's happening and what causes the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original [FindBugs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/findbugs/) plugin took this argument, but it has been depreciated. The replacement is [Warnings NG](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/) which also supports `unstableTotalAll`. But it was being used incorrectly. e.g.

```
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tools: [findBugs([pattern: '**/spotbugsXml.xml', unstableTotalAll: null])]
```

should have been

```
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, unstableTotalAll: 1, tools: [findBugs([pattern: '**/spotbugsXml.xml'])]
```

> after which there's a notable delay of usually 3-4 minutes in the Jenkins console

Jenkins seems very inefficient when uploading these files. A way to avoid this hit is to check the files for a static analysis issue before uploading it. e.g.

```
def files = findFiles(glob: '**/spotbugsXml.xml')

files.each { file ->
    println file.name
    println file.path
    def contents = readFile(file.path)
    if (contents.indexOf('<BugInstance')) {
        println 'Contains bugs so calling recordIssues'
    }
    else {
        println 'Does NOT contain bugs so NOT calling recordIssues'
    }
}
```